# Service worker not setting up correctly on deployed Firebase web-app for firebase cloud messaging

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-hosting

My Service worker works well enough for the token to be generated on my localhost, but whenever I deploy it doesn't work. If it makes a difference, I've used the create-react-app buildpack, so I run npm run build and then firebase deploy to get my app up and running (with build as the root folder). I've checked, and the firebase-messaging-sw.js does exist on my deployed version.
Here're the error message I receive in the console:

1. firebase-messaging-sw.js:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase-messaging.js' failed to load.
   at https://nearify-f2a4a.firebaseapp.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js:2:1
   (anonymous) @ firebase-messaging-sw.js:2
2. A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
3. firebase-messaging-sw.js:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase-messaging.js' failed to load.
   at https://nearify-f2a4a.firebaseapp.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js:2:1
   (anonymous) @ firebase-messaging-sw.js:2
   A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with the import scripts, we should instead be using '/_/' import scripts and not trying to use the 'https://' etc. You can find more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by `/_/`